# Comments plugin does not position well in FF or Chrome

Tags: css, facebook-comments

Seems that my comments plugin does not position well on my page. Instead of being centered the left margin of the plugin is at the center in Firefox and Chrome. Displays well in IE. The problem started two days and I did not change my code.

Page: http://www.yimago.com/radio1/

Code I used:

```
    <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:0.9em;">
<fb:comments-count href=http://www.yimago.com/radio1/></fb:comments-count> comments</div>

<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:0.9em;">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.yimago.com/radio1/" data-width="950" data-num-posts="5" text-align:left;></div>
</div>
```

Hello:
Added this to my CSS:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {position:relative; left:0px;}
```

Seems to solve my problem. Hope this help others.

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my CSS:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {left: 0px;}
```

Seems to solve my problem.